# How to filter listitems with user name or email when using Graph Api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

When I query graph API with URL like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields
```

it returns data like

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#...",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/...",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "\"XYZ\"",
        "createdDateTime": "2018-05-09T09:47:40Z",
        "eTag": "\"ZYX\"",
        "id": "1",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-05-09T09:47:40Z",
        "webUrl": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/something/Lists/Listname/1_.000",
        "createdBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": "john.smith@tenant.com",
                "id": "abcd-...",
                "displayName": "John Smith"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": "john.smith@tenant.com",
                "id": "abcd-...",
                "displayName": "John Smith"
            }
        },
        "parentReference": {},
        "contentType": {
            "id": "ABC..."
        },
        "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#...",
        "fields": {
            "@odata.etag": "\"DEF...\"",
            "Title": "John Smith party event",
            "EventDate": "2018-07-02T00:00:00Z",
```

so every entry has info about the creator. How can I use =filter to only keep values created by certain user?

I have tried following URLs but I only get errors:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?filter=createdBy eq 'john.smith@tenant.com'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?filter=createdBy/user/email eq 'john.smith@tenant.com'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?filter=author eq 'john.smith@tenant.com'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?filter=author/email eq 'john.smith@tenant.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it might sound like a straightforward query, surprisingly it seems filtering by user field is not supported except the case when *user id* is provided.

I have come up with the following solution

> there is at least one shortcoming of this approach, it requires two
>   requests to the server

1) Like i said, since the filtering by `user Id` is supported, first step would be to determine user `Id` by `Email` , for that purpose the following query could be utilized:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists('User Information List')/items?expand=fields(select=Id,Email)
```

*where `User Information List` system list stores user properties including Id and Email properties *

2) Once the user `Id` is resolved, the final query would be to apply the filtering by *user id* :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists('list-name')/items?filter=fields/<user-field-name>LookupId eq '<user-id>'
```

where

*`<user-field-name>LookupId` is a field which is getting exposed in addition to user field, in case of `Created` field the name should be `AuthorLookupId`*

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists('Tasks')/items?filter=fields/AuthorLookupId eq '10'
```

**Note**

> In some cases the following error is returned Field ''
>    cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed.
>    Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly'
>    header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on
>    large lists.
>
> In that case the following request header needs to be applied:
>
> Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the URL, The filter parameter is correct.

```
?filter=createdBy eq 'john.smith@tenant.com'
```

But i think the URL have some mistakes. May be it is not referring to correct place.

[Click here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=isRead%20eq%20false&method=GET&version=v1.0)

to test your API call.